# preg_replace exactly one character but no adjacent ones

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hello I need to replace mediawiki H1 markup (`=title=`) with double equal signs (`==Title==`).

I need however to leave Mediawiki H2 markup (`==title=`=) unchanged.

So the following:

```
=This is title=    ==This is subtitle== ===This is sub sub title===
```

should become:

```
==This is title==    ==This is subtitle== ===This is sub sub title===
```

using:

```
preg_replace('/(\={1})(.*)\\1/mU', '==\\2==', $s);
```

however I obtain

```
==This is title== ====This is subtitle==== ======This is sub sub title======
```

I gues it is greedily matching also the equal sign appearing inside the capture and doubling it...
Can anyone help?

Comment: (Not your current issue but a note) Your `m` modifier is not being used in that regex. `m` is so `^$` match each line of a string. You might have wanted `s` if you wanted `.` to include new lines.

Comment: please fix your question's markup first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<!=)(=[^=]+=)(?!=)
```

You can use this and replace this by `=\1=`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/32

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```
$str = '=This is title=    ==This is subtitle== ===This is sub sub title==='
$repl = preg_replace('/(?<!=)=(?!=)/', '==', $str);
//=> ==This is title==    ==This is subtitle== ===This is sub sub title===
```

`(?<!=)=(?!=)` will match a `=` that is not followed and preceded by `=`